# What and Where comes the actual usage of LARAVEL_START const defined in index.php of Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

When I'm looking into the Laravel Request Cycle, I encountered this line of code in the file `index.php`

```
define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
```

I didn't find any specification about this in Laravel documentation, may be it's not Laravel specific, who knows. Also I can't find any usage of this either in the documentation or any other place, please help me to understand what this line of code actually for?

Answer (score 5):

`define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));`

This line essentialy starts up the timer, so you can time how long it takes to boot up the framework, etc. Fun fact is that this constant is never used throughout entire framework, but you already noticed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `vendor\bin\phpunit` to run your tests

```
   public function __construct(?string $name = null, array $data = [], string $dataName = '')
   {
       parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);
       define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
   }
```

Add this to your constructor of `TestCase.php`